# How can I create a Visual Studio Code Python workspace?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, project, workspace

I'm trying to set up Python on Visual Studio Code on macOS. I have Python 2.7 and 3.5 interpreters installed on my computer. When I attempted to create my first Python file, the `import` modules were not found.

According to the various setup instructions I've seen, I'm supposed to be able to configure for my interpreter in "workspace settings." But I'm not sure I have a workspace, where to find it or how it is created.

When I go to the *Command Palette* and try to run *Python: Select Workplace Interpreter* I get an error that says:

> Please open a workspace to select the Python Interpreter

When I go to menu *File* → *Preference* → *Settings*, the *Workplace Settings* tab is greyed out and inactive.

[On this page](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings), under *User and Workspace Settings* it says, **"The workspace setting file is located under the .vscode folder in your project."**

If a workspace is related to a project then how is a project created? After far as I can see, Visual Studio Code only has the menu option for menu *File* → *New File*, not *New Project*.

Where is the `.vscode` folder? How is it created?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Visual Studio Code workspace is the directory which was opened by Visual Studio Code.

You should create a virtual environment and make Visual Studio Code using this virtual environment in user settings (file `settings.json`).

Example: Set `"python.pythonPath": "${workspaceRoot}/venv/bin/python"` in `settings.json` with `venv` is the virtual environment directory in the current workspace. Reopen Visual Studio Code.